# Struts2 select tag add/remove values using javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2

I wanted to add/remove values from the list box using javascript in struts2.
How could I do that?

```
<s:select label="Select Month" 
name="monthname" 
headerKey="1"
headerValue="-- Please Select --"
list="#{'01':'January','02':'February','03':'March','04':'April',
        '05':'May','06':'June','07':'July','08':'August','09':'September','10':
        'October','11':'November','12':'December'}"
/>
```

Let's say I wanted to remove January from the list or add new month in list by javascript in struts2. how do I will implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Struts2 has nothing to do with it.

I recommend you look at jQuery, because it makes this trivial:

```
<select>
 <option>Jan
 <option>Feb
 <option>Mar
 <option>Apr
 <option>Jun
</select>
<input type="button" id="removeJanuary" value="Remove January">

<script>
  $(function() {
   $('#removeJanuary').click(function() {
     $("option:contains('Jan')").remove();
   });
  });
</script>
```

See example: http://jsbin.com/ajoqa

Comment: Note that jQuery is *plain* jQuery from www.jquery.com, not "Struts-jQuery" (which is horrible IMO).

Comment: @Thiefmaster Which I think is implied by "Struts 2 had nothing to do with it". IMO a context-free complaint on a two-year old question is a disservice to future visitors.

Comment: Ooops, didn't look at the date. For some reason that question showed up on the front page...